# I want to move my index.html to the public folder in a vite react project but then I get an error

Tags: reactjs, vite

I have this structure of the project :

```
> Assets
> node_modules
> public
> src
  .gitignore
  .index.html
   package-lock.json
   package.json
   vite.config.js
```

and in my index html i have the script that points to `./src/main.jsx`

now the thing is that i want to move my index.html file in the public folder, i change my script from the index.html file to point to `../src/main.jsx`, i added the root key to point to "public" in the vite.config.js file but all I get is a blank page when i run npm run dev and this error message in the browser console:GET http://localhost:5173/src/main.jsx net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found).  Any ideeas?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Usually it would be in src and on a production build a index.html will be generated in the dist, which you'd use to serve in prod.

Answer (score 0):

During development, Vite is a server, and index.html is the entry point to your application.

You can refer this doc from vite:
https://vitejs.dev/guide/#index-html-and-project-root